# How to split a table by a repeated character in the first row in R?

Tags: r

I've been trying to split this table by the redundant table titles from the original .txt file so that I can group the data by these tables.

```
Gen <- read.delim(directory, sep = " ", header = FALSE, col.names = c("ID1", 
       "ID2", "type", "locus", "s", "dominance", "pop.", "Generation", 
       "prevalence", "Samp_Gen"), colClasses = c("character", "character", 
       "factor", "character", "numeric", "numeric", "character", "numeric", 
       "numeric", "numeric"))
Gen <- split(Gen, Gen$ID1=="Mutations")
```

A not a very good attempt I know but I can't find info relevant to my particular scenario. So how do you split a table by a repeated character in the first column? This is what my dataframe current looks like after using read.delim():

```
  ID1 ID2 type locus s     dominance pop. Generation prevalence Samp_Gen
1         #OUT: 1000    A /Users/tristan/Documents/SLiM_1/Results.txt      
2      Version:    
3  Populations:                                                           
4            p1  100    H                                                   
5    Mutations:                                                             
6  1 5418 m6   21469 -0.0200 0.5      p1      908         46       NA
7  2 5499 m1      68 1.0000  0.5      p1      920         154      NA
>
```

and here's the str() of the overall object:

```
> str(Gen)
'data.frame':   346355 obs. of  10 variables:
$ ID1       : chr  "#OUT:" "Version:" "Populations:" "p1" ...
$ ID2       : chr  "1000" "3" "" "100" ...
$ type      : Factor w/ 169 levels "","0","1","10",..: 56 1 1 57 1 66 58 58 
+ 67 61 ...
$ locus     : chr  "/Users/tristan/Documents/SLiM_1/Results.txt" "" "" "" 
+ ...
$ s         : num  NA NA NA NA NA -0.02 1 1 -0.04 0 ...
$ dominance : num  NA NA NA NA NA 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...
$ pop.      : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
$ Generation: num  NA NA NA NA NA 908 920 921 927 934 ...
$ prevalence: num  NA NA NA NA NA 46 154 46 13 9 ...
$ Samp_Gen  : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>
```

Thanks, Tristan
[each table in the file is of a different length, and there are exactly 1000 tables, the last column is where I'd like to have the table number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTZzV.jpg)

Comment: The first thing to do would be to get rid of the first 5 rows. The second thing to do would be to delete the picture of the data and post the text output of  dput applied to the revised version of Gen. At the moment you don't really have a [MCVE].

Comment: And ... can you more completely describe the goal. What are "redundant table titles", anyway?

Comment: If you want to skip the to 5 rows just use `skip=5` in your `read.delim` function. No need to split.

Comment: the first 5 rows are repeated for every table and are the redundant table titles I'm referring to, I don't need help removing the rows, I'm trying to split or otherwise separate the 1000 tables that follow these first 20 rows

Answer (score 0):

if your columns are separated by a space you can try `read.table(directory,sep = " ")`

but in general I would advise to use `fread` which is more robust.

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread(directory)
```

I suppose that `directory` refers to a .txt or .csv file that you want to read correctly.